# Finding all percentage combinations on multiple values

Tags: java, algorithm, math, combinations

I currently have a problem where I have an end result and the values that contribute to it, but I don't know what the weighting of each value is to the final result.

A simplified example: 11555 + -34.65 + 350 = 26

I don't know how to calculate the weighting mathematically, it has been suggested I use linear regression and a formula for Ordinary least squares. This is a bit beyond me to be honest and I was looking at an alternative solution.

What I propose to do, as I have a lot of sample data, is to use a brute force method over the values, where I use use a percentage of each value to contribute to the result, and compare and keep the percentages that provide the smallest difference.

What I'm struggling with is, how do I cover all percentage combinations for all values?

For example on 3 values the percentages would be something like this.

```
v1  v2  v3       %
98  1   1   =   100
97  2   1   =   100
96  2   2   =   100
95  3   2   =   100
94  3   3   =   100
.               
.               
.               
4   48  48  =   100
3   49  48  =   100
2   49  49  =   100
1   50  49  =   100
```

I hope this explanation is clear enough and I'd be grateful of any help you can give. I'm writing the program in Java.

Comment: This might be a good time to go learn about ordinary least squares regressions. It's the right tool for the job and should be much faster and more accurate than what you're proposing.

Comment: Whats wrong with just setting all the weights except for the last which scales you to the answer. IE `11555*0 + -34.65*0 + 350*0.0742`

Comment: Do you know that the percentages are without fractions, i.e. `int` values, not `double` values?

Comment: I did omit some details to keep things fairly simple. There are actually 15 values rather than 3, and not all results are accurate to their values. @templatetypedef you're probably right, might be a good time to dust off the old grey matter.

Comment: Only omit unnecessary details; insufficiently specified questions are unlikely to get you useful answers.

Comment: If the weights are supposed to sum to 1, you could just pick one value that's higher than the desired value, one that's lower (such values must exist, otherwise you can't scale anyway), and average out properly. E.g. if you want to scale your values, you could pick `350` and `-34.65` and solve `(1-t)*350 + t*(-34.65) = 26`. In general, solve `(1-t)c + ta = b` and get `t = (b-1)/(a-c)` for the case `a <= b <= c`; there's a number of obvious case distinctions to make sure `0 <= t <= 1`. If all weights need to be nonzero, there's a bit of fiddling to do to make it work anyway.

Comment: @G. Bach you're right, I probably should have omitted setting the scene as it's misdirected the actual question. I appreciate all comments.

Comment: @ezoray So do all the percents need to add to 1? That makes a big difference

Comment: @David Grinberg That is what I was proposing to try, as it seems a good place to start and I believe the values I meant to provide consistent contribution to the whole.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get all possible combinations with this code

```
for ( int i = 98; i > 0; i-- ) {
    for ( int j = 1; j+i < 100; j++ ) {
        int k = 100 - i - j;
        //do stuff with i,j,k
    }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks, this is a good heads up. I should probably avoid scaling this for my needs...